# Suppose $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere and $f_n$ are nonnegative measurable functions.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, almost-everywhere

Suppose $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere and $f_n$ are nonnegative measurable functions. If
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_Ef_n(x)d\mu=\int_Ef(x)d\mu,
\end{equation*}
then for any measurable subset $F\subseteq E$,
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_Ff_n(x)d\mu=\int_Ff(x)d\mu.
\end{equation*}

How do I prove this? What kind of theorem should I use? Thanks.

Comment: *Hint.* Use Fatou's lemma first to show that $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \int_{E}|f_n(x)-f(x)| \, \mathrm{d}\mu = 0. $$

Comment: Fatou's Lemma on $F$ and $F^c$.

Comment: @cmk Thanks for pointing it out. I edited the problem.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3386401/almost-complete-proof-that-int-a-f-n-to-int-a-f

Comment: @SangchulLee I managed to show $\lim\sup\int_E|f_n(x)-f(x)|d\mu=0$. Then how do I proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the following inequality? $$\left|\int_{\color{blue}F}(f_n-f)\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right|\leq\int_{\color{red}E}|f_n-f|\,\mathrm{d}\mu$$