# Show that $∫_E f=\lim ∫_E f_k $For any measurable set E .

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

assume $f_1,f_2,...$ are nonnegative functions in $L^1$, that $\lim f_k(x)=f(x)$ exists a.e., that $f \in L^1$, and that $\lim ∫f_K=∫f$ show that $\lim ∫|f_k-f|=0$.

show that this implies that for every measurable set $E$
$$  ∫_E f= \lim∫_E f_k .$$

I showed the first part with LDCT, but I don't know why that implies the other. Help!

Comment: Look for scheffé's lemma.

Comment: why $|∫_E f_k - ∫_E f| \leq ∫ |f_k-f| \rightarrow 0$ implies the second part? in [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3402149/show-that-int-limits-ef-lim-limits-n-to-infty-int-limits-e-f-n-for-any-m?answertab=votes#tab-top) @ε-δ  or Kavi Rama Murthy

Answer (score 1):

$f_n+ f-|f-f_n|\geq0$ and by Fatou's lemma
\begin{aligned}
\int 2f\,d\mu&\leq \liminf_n \int (f_n+f -|f-f_n|)\,d\mu\\
&\leq 2\int f\,d\mu +\liminf_n\Big(-\int|f-f_n|\,d\mu\Big)\\
&\leq 2\int f\,d\mu -\limsup_n\int|f-f_n|\,d\mu
\end{aligned}
This shows that $\limsup_n\int|f-f_n|\,d\mu=0$