# $f_n\rightharpoonup f$ in $L^P(E)$ iff $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_A f_n d\mu= \int_A f d\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence, solution-verification

Let $E$ be a measurable set and $1\le p <\infty$.Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a bounded sequence in $L^P(E)$ and $f \in L^P(E)$ . Then  $f_n\rightharpoonup  f$ in $L^P(E)$ iff for every measurable subset $A$ of $E$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_A f_n d\mu= \int_A f d\mu$$

This is Thm 10 ch.8 in Royden and Fitzpatrick, but has no proof. is the following correct?

I guess This $\Rightarrow $ is obvious by letting $g\in L^q$ to be a characteristic function. then $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_E f_n \chi_A d\mu= \int_E f\chi_A d\mu$.

but about $\Leftarrow $ direction; Suppose $E$ has finite measure and $p>1$.

I tried let $g_0\in L^q$ be any function.  Then;
\begin{align}
\int_E g_0f_n d\mu- \int_E g_0f d\mu 
& \le \int_E (g_0-\chi_A)(f_n-f) d\mu+ \int_E (f_n-f)\chi_A d\mu \\
& \le \|g_0-\chi_A\|_q\|f_n-f\|_p+ \frac{\epsilon}{2}   ~~~~ \small{\text{(1-Holder 2-by the above assumption)}}\\
&\le  \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} =\epsilon \\
\end{align}
where the last inequality follows from the since $g_0\in L^q$, and simple functions are dense in $L^q$, there exists $\chi_A$ such that $\|g_0-\chi_A\|_q\|f_n-f\|_p \le \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. $\square$

for $p=1$, and if $A$ is not finite measure I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3386401/almost-complete-proof-that-int-a-f-n-to-int-a-f

Comment: but this link is different, the my question is weak convergence in $L^p$ but the link is about almost everywhere convergence.

Comment: Oh, just realized that, okay, let me think.

Comment: The assertion must have missed some condition. For a sequence $(f_{n})\in L^{p}$ which is constant, say, $f_{n}=f$, and $f\notin L^{1}$, then how would one have the meaning of $\displaystyle\int_{E}f$? Of course, I am assuming that $E$ to be of infinite measure.

Comment: you're right, but the statements  does not want $f \in L^1(E)$ but requires $f_n,f \in L^1(A)$.

Comment: You see that $A$ could be any measurable subset of $E$, in particular, $A=E$ is allowed.

Comment: The theorem in the book clearly states that $f \in L^{p}(E)$.

Comment: @KaboMurphy do you think my proof is correct?

Comment: @stat_yale $\implies$ does not follow by taking a characteristic function because  a characteristic function need not be in $L^{q}$.

Comment: @KaboMurphy so it should be simple function, right? basically, can I say a simple function which is any constant $\alpha $ on $A$ and vanishes on $A^c$?