# $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere and $\int fn \rightarrow \int f$. Show that $\int_A fn \rightarrow \int_A f$ for any measurable A

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

**Question:** Suppose $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ is a measure space, $f_n$ is integrable and non-negative. If $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e. and $ \int f_n \rightarrow \int f$, then
$\int_A f_n \rightarrow \int_A f$  for every $A \in \mathcal{A}$.

**Attempt:** Since $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e., we have $f_n1_A \rightarrow f1_A$ a.e. for any $A \in \mathcal{A}$. So, there exists a set $B \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $f_n1_A \rightarrow f1_A$ on $B$ and $\mu(B^c)=0$. Therefore, $f_n1_A \leq f1_A+c$ on $B$ for some constant $c$. By generalized dominated convergence theorem, $\int_B 1_Af_n \rightarrow \int_B 1_Af$.

I couldn't continue and I did a mistake here. This problem is harder than how it seems. How can I solve it?

Comment: It seems that you simply need to check that $(f_n\mathbf 1_A)_{n\ge1}$ remains uniformly integrable.

Comment: Do you assume that $\mu$ is $\sigma-$finite?

Comment: They answered this question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3386401/almost-complete-proof-that-int-a-f-n-to-int-a-f?rq=1